# Dart get tracks element from String using RegExp

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

when i retrieve data from our website url, that return this output in one of rest api fields and i try to found if `tracks` is contained i get url from that which in this below `tracks` source is that i need to get

```dart
String test = """
<div class=\"wp-playlist wp-audio-playlist wp-playlist-light\">\n
<div class=\"wp-playlist-current-item\"></div>\n
<p>\t\t<audio controls=\"controls\" preload=\"none\" width=\"\n\t\t\t\t1118\t\"\n\t\t>
</audio></p>\n<div class=\"wp-playlist-next\"></div>\n<div class=\"wp-playlist-prev\">
</div>\n<p>\t<noscript></p>\n<ol>\n<li>
<a href='https://www.caferilik.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Anne-Baba-Biz-Suçluyuz-Muhafazakar-Ailelerde-Kuşak-Çatışması-Sesli-Kitap-www.caferilik.com_.mp3'>
Anne Baba Biz Suçluyuz - Muhafazakar Ailelerde Kuşak Çatışması (Sesli Kitap) www.caferilik.com<
/a></li>\n</ol>\n<p>\t</noscript><br />\n\t
<script type=\"application/json\" class=\"wp-playlist-script\">
{\"type\":\"audio\",\"tracklist\":true,\"tracknumbers\":true,\"images\":true,\"artists\":true,
\"tracks\":[{\"src\":\"https:\\/\\/www.caferilik.com\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2020\\/11\\/Anne-Baba-Biz-Su\\u00e7luyuz-Muhafazakar-Ailelerde-Ku\\u015fak-\\u00c7at\\u0131\\u015fmas\\u0131-Sesli-Kitap-www.caferilik.com_.mp3\",
\"type\":\"audio\\/mpeg\",\"title\":\"Anne Baba Biz Su\\u00e7luyuz - Muhafazakar Ailelerde Ku\\u015fak \\u00c7at\\u0131\\u015fmas\\u0131 (Sesli Kitap) www.caferilik.com\",\"caption\":\"\",
\"description\":\"\\\"Anne Baba Biz Su\\u00e7luyuz - Muhafazakar Ailelerde Ku\\u015fak \\u00c7at\\u0131\\u015fmas\\u0131 (Sesli Kitap) www.caferilik.com\\\".\",\"meta\":{\"length_formatted\":\"2:28:02\"},
\"image\":{\"src\":\"https:\\/\\/www.caferilik.com\\/wp-includes\\/images\\/media\\/audio.png\",\"width\":48,\"height\":64},\"thumb\":
{\"src\":\"https:\\/\\/www.caferilik.com\\/wp-includes\\/images\\/media\\/audio.png\",\"width\":48,\"height\":64}}]}</script>\n</div>\n
""";

test = test.replaceAll('\n', '').replaceAll('\t', '').replaceAll('\\', '');
```

i can found many `RegExp` to get `link` from string but i need to get source of `tracks`

Comment: What is the exact output you seek to get?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew getting `mp3` file link from tracks source

Comment: I doubt a regex will work the best here, you need 1) a HTML parser to get the right script tag value and 2) JSON parser to get the right value. I tried to come up with a regex, but it is not really nice, `new RegExp(r'<script[^>]*>[^<]*?"tracks"[^<]*?"(http\S*?\.mp3)"[^<]*?</script>').firstMatch(test)[1]`. Well, `[^<]*?</script>` seems redundant, but the pattern is really ugly.

Comment: @DolDurma the sample code looks like Java. Is this for Dart/Flutter=JS intended?

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Please kindly also upvote if my answer proved helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```dart
"tracks":\[{"src":"([^"]+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/kCCM8Z/1). When you put it inside code, the required value will be in the first group.

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "tracks":                '"tracks":'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {"src":"                 '{"src":"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```