# RegExp getting link from String except multiple www

Tags: regex, preg-match, regular-language

when i try to get links from String such as

> "hello world
> [https://www.sample.com/voices/2020/my-sound-www.sample.com"](https://www.sample.com/voices/2020/my-sound-www.sample.com%22)

i get multiple link from here because i have multiple `www`, how can i except that?

output:

1. https://www.sample.com/voices/2020/my-sound-www.sample.com
2. [www.sample.com](http://www.sample.com)

this output is incorrect and that should be one link not two link

```
https://www.sample.com/voices/2020/my-sound-www.sample.com
```

My regex pattern:

```regex
r"((https?:www\.)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)?"
```

Comment: How about: `https?://\S+` ?

Comment: @anubhava i get multiple link again, could you please include link should end with `.mp3` too?

Comment: @Toto no matter, my problem is have multiple `www`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no. this is another question, its like that only

Comment: With my regex, you'll get only one link from your example. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You should post the code you are using, with a real test case. Look, I have used [basically the same regex](https://regex101.com/r/idtemB/1), just removed the capturing groups, and even while the `g` flag is on, there is only one match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you can simply expect text from https://stackoverflow.com/q/65054040/1830228

Comment: It seems the main issue is that your regex only supports ASCII letters and you have other kind of letters in the text. Are you coding in Flutter Dart? As far as I know, there is still no support for `\p{L}` there. Maybe you should rely on a negated character class? Something like `(?:https?:(?:\\?\/\\?\/|www\.)|www\.)[^\s<>"']*\.mp3` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kCCM8Z/2))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, i'm coding in `Flutter`'s dart, i get error when i want to use that to test `final reg = RegExp(r'(?:https?:(?:\\?\/\\?\/|www\.)|www\.)[^\s<>"']*\.mp3');`

Comment: That is a syntax issue, you must escape a `'` inside a single quoted string literal with another single quote.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes sure, i upvoted too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```dart
final reg = RegExp(r'(?:https?:(?:\\?\/\\?\/|www\.)|www\.)[^\s<>"'']*\.mp3');
final m = reg.firstMatch(test);
print(m.group(0));
// => https://www.caferilik.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Anne-Baba-Biz-Suçluyuz-Muhafazakar-Ailelerde-Kuşak-Çatışması-Sesli-Kitap-www.caferilik.com_.mp3
```

Here, the pattern is

```dart
(?:https?:(?:\\?\/\\?\/|www\.)|www\.)[^\s<>"']*\.mp3
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kCCM8Z/2)

**Details**:

- `(?:https?:(?:\\?\/\\?\/|www\.)|www\.)` - `http`, followed with an optional `s` char, then `:` and then either `//` with an optional `\` before each `/` or `www.`, just or `www.`
- `[^\s<>"']*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace, `<`, `>`, `"` and `'`
- `\.mp3` - an `.mp3` string.